# add class to an element that has classname treeview

Tags: jquery

I got an error with this code

```
$(this + '.treeview').addClass('active');
```

The error is

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLLIElement].treeview

how to correct that?

Comment: `this` in the context above is a DOM element, and you're trying to concatenate it with a string which won't work. The `$` constructor will take either a DOM element, a selector (string), but not both. What was your intention in trying to combine the two?

Comment: I have li element as main menu that has sub menu element li, when sub menu is clicked the main menu is also clicked because the sub menu is in main menu element. The problem was to set the main menu active, 

But then I put stopPropagation in the sub menu elemen to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're concatenating an object and a string. If what you want to do is find a child of the DOM node represented by `this`, you first need to create a `jQuery` instance:

```
$(this)
```

and then use the [api](http://api.jquery.com/) to select the children that match the class:

```
$(this).children('.treeview')...
```

But if you're looking for any descendants, you'd use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(this).find('.treeview')...
```

Or you could use the shorthand form:

```
$('.treeview', this)...
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem by using @zzzzBov answer

Here is the full code

```
$('.dinz-submenu').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.sidebar-menu li').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('treeview')) {
        $('.sidebar-menu li ').removeClass('active');
        $('.treeview-menu').slideUp();

        if(!$(this).find('.treeview-menu').is(':visible')){
            $(this).children('.treeview-menu').slideDown();
        }
        $(this).addClass('active');

        return false;
    } else {
        if ($(this).hasClass('dinz-submenu')) {
            $('.treeview-menu li ').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.treeview-menu').slideUp();
            $('.sidebar-menu li ').removeClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```